# Add local NuGet server to server list with .VSIX

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, vsix

I would like to provide a Visual Studio extension (.VSIX) which adds a local NuGet server to the list of NuGet servers. Is this possible? Is there a generic way to change Visual Studio options by a .VSIX??

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need VSIX? List of NuGet servers (or more precisely, package sources) is kept in plain XML file at this path: **%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config**

(Package source does not have to be a server, it could be a folder or network share as well.)